# Multiple Paypal Merchant Accounts on one website

Tags: paypal

This is what I want to do?
I am building a online fundraising platform where people can create a page on my site and setup their payment colletion facility so the funds can go directly into their account. 
I already have Stripe which allows me to do that where users essentially provide their Stripe account details and all those funds go into that account directly instead of mine.

Does anyone know if this is possible in Paypal as well?

I couldn't find it anywhere.

Example where it works now?
Ebay is perfect example where sellers setup their account and provide their paypal details. Then all funds go into their paypal account.

To be honest, I haven't seen this anywhere else on the same website domain.

Any solution ideas would be great!

Comment: Hi Coder - sounds like you may want to initiate PayPal adaptive paymnent for PayPal to PayPal payments and for credit cards you can use Braintree's marketplace. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/, braintree -->https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/overview?_ga=2.33726627.302767466.1506832608-292007846.1488991829

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, that product is not available in Australia (paypal or braintree). We will just have to wait :(

Comment: Actually that product has been sunset since my last.